# How to split the values in field

Tags: apex, string

A `text field` (let say field name is `Test`) in account has multiple values like `aaa;123;456;abhu;ueie;4;45;`. I want to split the values and store them in another variable like integer or string(what ever the variable is).

I want solution for this using `apex class` and don't have no idea how to start. Can any one please help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [split](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method of `String` class

> Returns a list that contains each substring of the String that is
>   terminated by either the regular expression regExp or the end of the
>   String.

```
String testString = 'aaa;123;456;abhu;ueie;4;45;';
List<String> values = testString.split(';');
for(String value:values){
    System.debug(value);
}
```

will result in:

```
aaa
123
456
...
```